# Yet another Bluetooth problem with 21.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth

My Bluetooth headset paired with my Intel NUC after installing 21.04. But now, for some reason, despite being paired it is disconnected and will not reconnect! The connection button will not work....it will not stay connected. What do I need to do please to resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: "Forget" the device and pair again.

Comment: Tried that lots of times......no difference!